# Call method in other class from onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` class in a java file, and then I have a bunch of other activities where I will be calling this `AsyncTask` class. Now the `doInBackground` method is always doing the same thing, but then in each activity I want to do different things with the returned data. So it looks something like this

```
public class MakePOSTAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... obj) {
   //thisIsAlwaysTheSame
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String  string){
   //I want to make a method call in the activity where I am calling
   //this AsyncTask??
}
```

So how can I call a method in different activities, obviously it will have the same name, but I cant do `ActivityName.method();` as I will be calling it in different activities?

Thanks

Comment: You can pass a reference to the activity through the Async constructor/setter or use  @StenSoft's option.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks, could you add a little more about what you mean, please?

Answer (score 3):

Pass reference to your activity to MakePOSTAsync. The best approach is to store it inside AsyncTask as a WeakReference - this will prevent reference leaks. Also you actually should create an interface, and pass reference to this interface. Each of your activities will implement this interface.

Example code:

```
// Common interface
  interface DataLoadCallback {
    void startLoading();
    void loaded(String someData);
  }

  // Some activity or fragment
  public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DataLoadCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      new MakePOSTAsync(this).execute();
      // dont forget to manage lifetime of AsyncTask, like
      // cancel it in case of activity gets destroyed. Or switch to Loader.
    }
  }

  // In MakePOSTAsync.java
  public class MakePOSTAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {

    private WeakReference<DataLoadCallback> callbackRef;

    public MakePOSTAsync(DataLoadCallback callback) {
      callbackRef = new WeakReference<DataLoadCallback>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      DataLoadCallback ref = callbackRef.get();
      if (ref != null) {
        ref.startLoading(); // show progress in activity?
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... obj) {
      //thisIsAlwaysTheSame
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
      DataLoadCallback ref = callbackRef.get();
      if (ref != null) {
        ref.loaded(string);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, would you mind post a bit of sample code, just to make it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a callback interface:

```
public class MakePOSTAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<Callback> mCallback;

    interface Callback {
        void doSomething();
    }
    public MakePOSTAsync(Callback callback){
        mCallback = new WeakReference<Callback>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string){
        if(mCallback.get() != null){
            mCallback.get().doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

And have your activity implement it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    MakePOSTAsync.Callback{

    ...

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {

    }

    //Then you can start your task, passing in the callback implementation in the constructor
    private void startTask() {
        new MakePOSTAsync(this).execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement it in `MakePOSTAsync`:

```
public abstract class MakePOSTAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... obj) {
       //thisIsAlwaysTheSame
    }

    protected abstract void onPostExecute(String string);
}
```

But in activity:

```
// eg. here
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    MakePOSTAsync task = new MakePOSTAsync() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String  string){
            // Do whatever you need for this activity
        }
    }
    // etc.
}
```